# Guardar un dato de un array en una variable con PDO

Tags: pdo

Estoy capturando los datos de mi tabla con PDO, pero necesito guardar en una variable diferente el campo perfil, logro imprimirlo pero no se como guardar solo ese dato en una variable especifica, ya intente haciéndolo de la siguiente manera:$perfil=  $datos[2] pero no funciona.Gracias

```
<?php
    try {

        $base = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=prueba_usuarios","root","");
            $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql="SELECT usuario,pass_ejus,perfil FROM users_ejus WHERE usuario=:usuario AND pass_ejus=:passj";
            $resultado=$base->prepare($sql);

            $login=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["usuario"]));
            $passw=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["passj"]));
            $resultado->bindValue(":usuario",$login);
            $resultado->bindValue(":passj",$passw);

            while( $datos = $resultado->fetch() ){
                        $perfil=  $datos[2];
                        
                 }      
            $resultado->execute();
            $numero_registro=$resultado->rowCount();
            
        

            if($numero_registro!=0){

                    //echo"<h2>Si esta conectando </h2>";
                    session_start();

                    $_SESSION["usuario"]=$_POST["usuario"];
                    if($perfil=="1"){
                            include("menu1.html");  
                        
                 }
                     
                
           
                    }else{
                                while( $datos = $resultado->fetch() ){
                        echo $datos[2];
                        
                 }                  
                        include("menu2.html");   
           
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public static function obtener () {
    $query = self::connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `user_ejus` WHERE `user`=:user and `pass`=:pass");
    $query->execute(["user" => $user,"pass"  => $pass]);
    return $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

$resultado = obtener();
echo $resultado[perfil];
```

usando consultas preparadas es mas sencillo, esto devuelve un array asociativo (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC), que es almacenado en $resultado, y para acceder a ella es mediante $resultado[perfil]

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta, pero como hago para guardar ese $resultado[perfil], en otra variable diferente a resultado, lo que requiero es sacar ese dato para poderlo operar en un if.

Comment: Lo estoy haciendo de esta manera

 public static function obtener () {
    $query = self::connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `user_ejus` WHERE `user`=:user and `pass`=:pass");
    $query->execute(["user" => $user,"pass"  => $pass]);
    return $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

$resultado = obtener();
$perfil= $resultado[perfil];
Pero no funciona

Comment: ya esta guardado en $resultado, si quieres operar con el simplemente es if ($resultado["perfil"])

Comment: Lo tengo de esta manera pero me genera error :
Use of undefined constant perfil - assumed 'perfil' in 
if($resultados[perfil]=="1"){
          
       include("menu1.html");   
        
      
         }else{

Comment: que tipo de dato es perfil en la base de datos?

Comment: El tipo de dato es varchar

Comment: usa echo var_dump($resultado["perfil"]) a ver si te muestra un array

Comment: No me muestra el arreglo genera error por las comillas, 

class A
{
 public static function obtener () {
    $query = self::connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `user_ejus` WHERE `user`=:user and `pass`=:pass");
    $query->execute(["user" => $user,"pass"  => $pass]);
    return $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $resultados = obtener();
    echo $resultados[perfil];

    
}

 
}
Cree la clase de esta manera, pero cuando coloco el resultado en el if sigue presentando error que no encuentra esa variable para hacer la operacion